# Spring boot application create an object using properties from application properties

Tags: spring-boot

Values from application.properties can only be certain types, like String, int and so on. But often one needs an object, that is generated based on those values. In the following example, timeout is read from application.properties, but a Duration type property is actually used. Therefore, I made it into a bean, and inject it whenever needed. Is there another method to make value transfered from certain types to other types? (other types are actually used)

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.app")
@RefreshScope
public class AiplatformFaceProperties {
    int timeout;

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "timeoutDuration")
    Duration createTimeoutDuration() {
        return Duration.ofSeconds(timeout);
    }

}


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("timeoutDuration")
    private Duration timeoutDuration;
```

Moreover, by using a getter like this, I can get a transformed Duraiton, but it is constructed everytime needed, I would like to have a constructed-once property, like those certain tayed values.

```
Duration getTimeoutDuration() {
  return Duration.ofSeconds(timeout);
}
```